# I deleted Main.Storyboard, recoverd it but

Tags: xcode, xcode7.1

I deleted Main.Storyboard. I recovered it by dragging it back to the project in xcode. However, now it does not show in Base.Iproj (other than that everything is working).

I tried moving it back to Base.Iproj but when I do that, nothing shows in xcode.

What do I need to do to restore the project?

Comment: First move it to `Base.Iproj`, then drag it to project in xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First move the `Storyboard` file to `Base.Iproj`, then drag it to project in Xcode. This will add the file to the project properly.